# Как передать с помощью ADB на эмулятор кириллицу?

Tags: android, adb

Как передать русский текст на эмулятор андроид через командную строку, используя ADB без установки на компьютер дополнительных скриптов?

Знаю, что эта команда не поддерживает кириллицу:

```
adb shell input text <string>
```

Пробовал копировать в буфер и вставлять, используя команду:

```
adb shell input keyevent 279
```

Тоже никакого результата, хотя вручную вставить получается. Есть какие-нибудь идеи, как победить это?